# numba.jit give function and signature as inputs

Tags: python, benchmarking, signature, jit, numba

My objective:

I have a function and I want to see how it performs for a list of numba options/parameters (nopython, no gil, parallel, etc. and Signature!)

so I want to do something like:

```
def foo(a):
   return a*2


for signature in list:
   foo_jit = numba.jit(foo, signature)
   
   print("speed for jitted func given signature")
```

Sadly this raises an error, because @numba.jit() as decorator takes a signature for the first input, and numba.jit() as a function takes a function as input. I've tried assigning the signature before jitting the function, but you can't jit a function twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To test such approach, I would give a try to defining a function within a loop:

```
for signature in list:

    @jit(signature)
    def foo(a):
       return a*2

    start = time.time()
    foo(whatever_data_you_have)
    end = time.time()
    print("Elapsed (with compilation) = %s" % (end - start))
```

You can of course read [in the guide](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/user/5minguide.html) that first time is with compilation, thus if you want time without compilation, add one more time the testing block, this it will load from cache and wont count compilation in elapsed time.

Comment: Thank you very much, this works!

And thanks for mentioning the compilation times. I just realised functions are being always cached by jit, what's then the difference when you use @jit(cache=true)??

Comment: @Darkonia `@jit(cache=true)` will save compiled function on drive for later use so it doesn't need to compile, however I was unable to find info if this works for same named question and different signature, probably will overwrite the previous same named function, I am considering opening a question for this